# How to write a closed term with this type?

Tags: lambda-calculus

`X→Y →(X+Y)×Y`

I'm confused about how to get the type `(X + Y)`.
If I assume `m: (X + Y), n: X, k: Y`
then I can get $${m:X+Y \vdash \lambda n:X.\lambda k:Y.<m, k>}$$
which get the right type. But I can't reduce the context `m: X + Y`.
So, could anyone tell me how to make it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $X+Y$ is in the result type. Why put it into the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a new type constructor is defined, it comes with *introduction* and *elimination* terms. These are *part of the definition*.

In the case of sums, the following are **part of the definition** of what it means to have $X + Y$:

- given types $X$ and $Y$ there is a type $X + Y$
- given a term $e : X$ there is a term $\mathsf{inl}(e) : X + Y$
- given a term $e' : Y$ there is a term $\mathsf{inr}(e') : X + Y$
- (there is also an eliminator and equations which I am not writing down here)

So I think this is the point you missed: we do not just say "there is a type $X + Y$" without anything else, as that would be completely useless. We also provide ways of *constructing* (introducing) and *deconstructing* (eliminating) terms of the new type.

Now that we know that $\mathsf{inl}$ and $\mathsf{inr}$ are there by definition of sum types, it is easy:
$$\lambda x : X . \lambda y : Y . \langle \mathsf{inr}(y), y\rangle.$$
By the way, Haskell's [djinn](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn-th-0.0.1/docs/Language-Haskell-Djinn.html) package can help you with this (I'd show a demo but OSX El Capitan broke cabal).

Comment: But how can I make sure that inl(x) : X + Y, the right part is of type Y? not H or J and something like this?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I think you meant $\mathsf{inr} : Y \to X + Y$

Comment: Fixed the typo and explained some more.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thank you for your answer, it help me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

However you've formulated sums, you ultimately have two constructors, i.e. functions with type $X\to X+Y$ and $Y \to X+Y$.  Often these are called `inl`/`inr`.  In Haskell they are `Left` and `Right`.  If you're using a Church-encoding, you should work out the right lambda terms.

So, since you have both an $X$ and a $Y$, you have two separate ways of filling in the first component of the result tuple.

Comment: I'm still confused about how to get the type X or Y, if I have the type X + Y...Could you give me a hint? Thanks a lot.